# Echo return values from rows from db

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

Does it make difference to get the value of result set when using alias names and join in the SQL generated using zend framwork.

Regarding to the sql resulted from the selected answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903687/inner-join-in-zend-framework) I want to print all result in .phtml file.

I make like this

```
 <?php   
   foreach($this->rows as $row){
          echo $row->visit_id . '  ' . $row->rep_id . '  '.$row->target;

  ?>
```

When I print the size of `$this->rows` it returns the correct number of rows, but it doesn't print any thing?!

**Edit** 
here's what I get when I print $rows

```
    Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo Object ( [_fetchMode:protected] => 2 [_stmt:protected] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT `r`.`rep_id`, `r`.`visit_id`, `v`.`target`, `v`.`visit_id` FROM `visit_report_tb` AS `r` INNER JOIN `inspection_visits_tb` AS `v` ON v.visit_id=r.visit_id WHERE (r.visit_id = 1) ) [_adapter:protected] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql Object ( [_pdoType:protected] => mysql [_numericDataTypes:protected] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [INT] => 0 [INTEGER] => 0 [MEDIUMINT] => 0 [SMALLINT] => 0 [TINYINT] => 0 [BIGINT] => 1 [SERIAL] => 1 [DEC] => 2 [DECIMAL] => 2 [DOUBLE] => 2 [DOUBLE PRECISION] => 2 [FIXED] => 2 [FLOAT] => 2 ) [_defaultStmtClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo [_config:protected] => Array ( [dbname] => inspection [username] => root [password] => 123456 [charset] => [persistent] => [options] => Array ( [caseFolding] => 0 [autoQuoteIdentifiers] => 1 [fetchMode] => 2 ) [driver_options] => Array ( ) ) [_fetchMode:protected] => 2 [_profiler:protected] => Zend_Db_Profiler Object ( [_queryProfiles:protected] => Array ( ) [_enabled:protected] => [_filterElapsedSecs:protected] => [_filterTypes:protected] => ) [_defaultProfilerClass:protected] => Zend_Db_Profiler [_connection:protected] => PDO Object ( ) [_caseFolding:protected] => 0 [_autoQuoteIdentifiers:protected] => 1 [_allowSerialization:protected] => 1 [_autoReconnectOnUnserialize:protected] => ) [_attribute:protected] => Array ( ) [_bindColumn:protected] => Array ( ) [_bindParam:protected] => Array ( ) [_sqlSplit:protected] => Array ( [0] => SELECT `r`.`rep_id`, `r`.`visit_id`, `v`.`target`, `v`.`visit_id` FROM `visit_report_tb` AS `r` INNER JOIN `inspection_visits_tb` AS `v` ON v.visit_id=r.visit_id WHERE (r.visit_id = 1) ) [_sqlParam:protected] => Array ( [0] => SELECT `r`.`rep_id`, `r`.`visit_id`, `v`.`target`, `v`.`visit_id` FROM `visit_report_tb` AS `r` INNER JOIN `inspection_visits_tb` AS `v` ON v.visit_id=r.visit_id WHERE (r.visit_id = 1) ) [_queryId:protected] => )
```

Comment: Is `$row` really and object or is it an array? You could try to print it using `print_r`.

Comment: It returns Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo Object (.....)

Comment: try `print_r( $this->rows->toArray() );` and look at the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the query you accepted in the other question, your field names should be as you expect.

I usually just var_dump `$row` to see what's there is what I expect:

```
<?php   
   foreach($this->rows as $row){
          //Zend_Debug::dump() provides formatted debug info, the second argument is a label 
          Zend_Debug::dump($row, 'Row')
  ?>
```

This should give you a pretty good idea of what each row contains with out all the baggage that `$rows` has.

Answer (score 0):

The row is not an object, its an array and it can be get like this:

```
print $row['rep_id']
```

Comment: Did you try print "$row->visit_id"; this?

Comment: Yes I did it returns nothing!

Comment: And what print_r($row) gives?;

Comment: Array ( [rep_id] => 1 [visit_id] => 1 [target] => loca1 ) Array ( [rep_id] => 2 [visit_id] => 1 [target] => loc2 )

Comment: I fix the problem, I print $row['rep_id']

Comment: The problem was the return values ($row) was array not object, it works with echo and print!

Comment: Yes, I discover that when I print_r($row) not all $rows

Comment: Please remove "Use print instead of echo. like"  and only talk about the return values are arrays not objects in order to mark it as true.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, and that's why I pointed You to ReferenceMap i Zend_Db_Tables. Check my answer to Your previous question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905206/1278879

Using my code from Your previous question You could've done it like this:

```
foreach ($reportRowset as $reportRow) {
   echo $reportRow->visit_id . '  ' . $reportRow->rep_id . '  '.$visitRow->target;
}
```

And that's piece of cake

Comment: I want to get the result as object not array, but I think your way is not peace of cake :S

Comment: $visitRow and $reportRow are Objects! They are Zend_Db_Table_Row. Of course You can override this by setting protected property $_rowClass in Your Zend_Db_Table classes (i. e. Visit and Report class - taking from my previous answer).